# Edit checkout shipment form

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping, form-validation

After upgrade magento version 2.3.1 to 2.3.3, i face an error in checkout shipment form, there is "county and country" text field. So i need to hide "county" field in checkout shipment form. Is it possible, let me know thanks?

[image]

Comment: is that country field(the text filed one) a custom field? as I guess the one with dropdown is the magento default country picker.

Comment: How to remove this field?

Comment: well you should check and find how it is added, may be it is added via one of you module. For example you can check this path
app/design/frontend/VENDOR/THEME/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

See if something is added.

Comment: try to replace the checkout folder from fresh magento to this one and then check. And still not work then disable third party extension which is related to checkout and then check.

Comment: Okay, will check it.